# How to GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table showing transaction of a customer .My objective is to list the customer with latest transaction(MAX trans_Date)

The table looks like this

```
**tblTransaction**
transId   custServId  transDate
  10          3       2013-12-24 11:10:57.390     
  11          4       2013-12-25 11:10:57.390
  12          5       2013-12-26 11:10:57.390
  13          6       2013-12-27 11:10:57.390

**tblCustomerService**
 custServId   custId    custServices
   3            2       Bill Payment
   4            2       Recharge
   5            3       Renewal
   6            4       BillPayment

**tblCustomer**
 custId      custName    custAddress
  2           Arun        test1
  3           Rahul       test2
  4           Kumar       test3
```

Desired Result should be

```
 custId   custName    LastTransactionDate
   2        Arun      2013-12-25 11:10:57.390
   3        Rahul     2013-12-26 11:10:57.390
   4        Kumar     2013-12-27 11:10:57.390
```

I have tried out the following query but i am not getting the desired result.Here all the values are displaying

```
Select c.Cust_CustID as custId,
c.Cust_CustName as custName,
c.Cust_Mobno as custMob,
c.Cust_EmailID as custEmail,
Max(e.Enq_EnqDate) as transactionDate   
from dbo.EP_Enquiry e
inner join  dbo.EP_CustomerServices cs on cs.CustServ_CustServID=e.CustServ_CustServID
inner join dbo.EP_Customer c on c.Cust_CustID=cs.CustServ_CustID
group by c.Cust_CustID,c.Cust_CustName,c.Cust_Mobno,c.Cust_EmailID,e.Enq_EnqID
order by transactionDate desc
```

Comment: Please provide the query that you have tried, so the community can help you on that.

Comment: updated the question.kindly look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
   tblCustomer.*,
   T.MaxDate
FROM tblCustomer
LEFT JOIN
 ( SELECT tblCustomerService.custId,
          MAX(tblTransaction.transDate) as MaxDate
   FROM tblTransaction
   JOIN tblCustomerService on 
        tblCustomerService.custServId=tblTransaction.custServId
   GROUP BY tblCustomerService.custId
  ) as T 
     on tblCustomer.custId = T.custId
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86b505/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
SELECT TC.custID,TC.custName, TTRANS.transDate FROM 
tblTransaction TTRANS
INNER JOIN 
tblCustomerService TCS ON TTRANS.custServId   = TCS.custServId  
INNER JOIN tblCustomer TC ON TCS.custId     = TC.custId    
WHERE TTRANS.transDate  = (SELECT MAX(transDate) FROM tblTransaction b WHERE TCS.custId = b.custId)
```